# Prestashop RDFa Breadcrumb

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, breadcrumbs, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

i'm trying to implement RDFa breadcrum in a site of mine using Prestashop 1.6 version.I'm using this guide http://nemops.com/prestashop-rich-snippets-breadcrumbs/#.VuBX9Jx96Uk to alter the breadcrumb.tpl and to override the Tools class. I get the desired results at the googles testing tools but i cant get a url and a title for the last category.
E.G

```
Category1 -> Category2 -> Category3
```

I only get links in the breadcrumb for the first 2 categories , i think it's excluding the 3rd because it's the active one , but because of that behaviour , an `<span property="v:title" class="navigation_page">{$path}</span>` with an empty url and title is returned. So i think that by just enabling the last category to be a link i will solve my problem. The problem is that although i've searched the Tools getPath() function i haven't managed to detect the last category and turn it into a link. Is there a way to alter the code in order to have a breadcrumb containing only links including the last category?

Comment: I can give you a snippet on how to implement microdata version of breadrumbs if you're interested

Comment: I think that would be great

Comment: https://github.com/PrestaShop/community-theme-16/blob/dev/themes/community-theme-16/breadcrumb.tpl It's a bit hacky, but work very well, haven't encountered any bugs recently

Comment: The snippet works like a charm,  I'll implement it using RDFa and I'll update the post In the next day

Comment: Haha I myself forgot that this template enables to do anything :D